# Sharing WiFi Credentials with Raspberry Pi 4B over iPhone

Tags: wifi, ethernet, bridge

I have a consistently working WiFi-to-Ethernet Bridge (using [this](https://www.willhaley.com/blog/raspberry-pi-wifi-ethernet-bridge/) tutorial), but would like the ability to easily share my network credentials with the Pi via my iPhone if my main WiFi network ever changes. I've looked into sending data over BLE but not many options for Apple users exist.

The best solution I could find is creating a Raspberry Pi Access Point that automatically switches to client mode if a valid SSID is in range. I've just been SSH'ing into the Pi when it runs as an Access Point, providing the credentials, then forcing a reboot. This also works great by itself, but trying to combine this solution with the WiFi-to-Ethernet bridge either breaks the bridge or the access point.

Does anyone know of a 'modified' Raspberry Pi AP to Client setup that also allows a bridged ethernet connection, or a better way to share network credentials with the Pi when a new network needs to be connected to?

Thanks for your help!